# Place a date in a range based on date values

Tags: vba, excel

I have a dataset in excel that can be reproduced with the following routine:

```
sub dummy_data

  Sheets("Blad1").Cells(20, 2).FormulaLocal = 2014
  Sheets("Blad1").Cells(21, 2).FormulaLocal = 2014
  Sheets("Blad1").Cells(22, 2).FormulaLocal = 2014
  Sheets("Blad1").Cells(23, 2).FormulaLocal = 2014

  Sheets("Blad1").Cells(20, 3).FormulaLocal = 5
  Sheets("Blad1").Cells(21, 3).FormulaLocal = 6
  Sheets("Blad1").Cells(22, 3).FormulaLocal = 7
  Sheets("Blad1").Cells(23, 3).FormulaLocal = 8

  Sheets("Blad1").Cells(20, 5).FormulaLocal = "27-02-2014"
  Sheets("Blad1").Cells(21, 5).FormulaLocal = "03-03-2014"
  Sheets("Blad1").Cells(22, 5).FormulaLocal = "10-03-2014"
  Sheets("Blad1").Cells(23, 5).FormulaLocal = "17-03-2014"

  Sheets("Blad1").Cells(2, 5).FormulaLocal = "Factuurmomenten"
  Sheets("Blad1").Cells(3, 5).FormulaLocal = "28-02-2014"  
  Sheets("Blad1").Cells(4, 5).FormulaLocal = "12-03-2014"
end sub
```

I need to write a VBA macro that takes the values in the range E3:E4 and places it below in the relevant week. So the value in cell (3,5) should be placed after 27-01-2014 and before 3-2-2014 in cell F20.

I wrote the following code:

```
  Sub test()

    Range("E3").Select
    Set x = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))

    Range("E20").Select
    Set y = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))

    For Each cell In x
        For Each cell2 In y

            cell3 = cell2.Offset(1, 0).Value

            If (cell >= cell2) Then
                If (cell <= cell3) Then
                    MsgBox("Jes")
                    End If
                End If

        Next cell2
    Next cell

End Sub
```

I think I'm almost there, but I just need something now that places the relevant date in the relevant cell. So instead of MsgBox("yes"), it should be placed in the relevant cell.

Any feedback on how I can do this? And if there is a better and more efficient way to reach my goal, I'm open for it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
Sub test()

    Range("E3").Select
    Set x = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))

    Range("E20").Select
    Set y = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))

    For Each cell In x
        For Each cell2 In y

            If (cell >= cell2) Then
                If (cell <= cell2.Offset(1, 0).Value) Then
                cell2.Offset(0, 1).Value = cell.Value
                    End If
                End If

        Next cell2
    Next cell

End Sub
```

I don't fully understand why to loop through cells, if there's only one desired cell, however, if it was for demonstration -which I think- and you really need it in loop, I fixed it that way.
PS: Try to explicitly state what you need, there is a difference for asking a [function and doing a sub](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/function-sub.html)